# Z3 solver for string based constraints

Tags: c#, z3

I am trying to use Z3 to solve string constraints using Z3 C# API.

So far, i have researched examples but Z3 seems to support only number based algebraic expressions such as :

```
x > 0
y = x + 1 
y < 3
```

which can be expressed using z3 c# API as:

```
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
    Expr x = ctx.MkConst("x", ctx.MkIntSort());
    Expr y = ctx.MkConst("y", ctx.MkIntSort());
    Expr zero = ctx.MkNumeral(0, ctx.MkIntSort());
    Expr one = ctx.MkNumeral(1, ctx.MkIntSort());
    Expr three = ctx.MkNumeral(3, ctx.MkIntSort());

    Solver s = ctx.MkSolver();
    s.Assert(ctx.MkAnd(ctx.MkGt((ArithExpr)x, (ArithExpr)zero), ctx.MkEq((ArithExpr)y, 
        ctx.MkAdd((ArithExpr)x, (ArithExpr)one)), ctx.MkLt((ArithExpr)y, (ArithExpr)three)));
    Console.WriteLine(s.Check());

    Model m = s.Model;
    foreach (FuncDecl d in m.Decls)
            Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " -> " + m.ConstInterp(d));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is there any way to evaluate string based expressions such as:

```
string S1;
string S2:
string S3;
S3=S1+S2;
```

Any help with string based constraints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 does not by itself support strings as a primitive data-type.
You could give z3-str a try, though (https://github.com/z3str/Z3-str).

There is also the S3 system from NUS, described in ccs 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Z3 supports String type now with some limitations. Reference here: [Z3 solver for string based constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614720/z3-solver-for-string-based-constraints)